# Get total number of documents in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to mongodb and trying to get the total number of records from a collection. I am using node express.

My code -

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Patient = require('../models/patient');

/*
 * GET /patient route to retrieve all the patients.
 */
function getPatients(req, res) {
    let page = Number(req.params.page);
    let pageSize = Number(req.params.pageSize);
    let start = (page-1)*pageSize;

    //Query the DB and if no errors, send all the patients
    let total = Patient.count({});
    //console.log(total);
    let query = Patient.find({});
    query.skip(start);
    query.limit(pageSize);
    query.exec((err, patients) => {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        //If no errors, send them back to the client
        res.json({total:total, page:page, pageSize:pageSize, items:patients});
    });
}
```

The error message I am getting is --

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `res.json({total:total});` if that works fine try it with `page` then with `pageSize` and lastly `items:patients`, that should help you find out wich item is a circular structure.

Comment: Also ES6 allows you to: `res.json({total, page, pageSize, items:patients});`

Comment: The issue is in getting total number of records not the response. I tried as you suggested but this doesn't seem to be working - `let total = Patient.count();`

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the error is coming form above and not from inside the anonymous `query.exec((err, patients) => {` callback?

Comment: Yes I am quite sure. The exec function gives me correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoose count is an async function (returning a Promise) that can also be used with a callback.

Your error must be related with the `res.json` of a promise and not its result itself.

### Here is a solution with Promise (async/await syntax):

```
async function getPatients(req, res) {
    let page = Number(req.params.page);
    let pageSize = Number(req.params.pageSize);
    let start = (page-1)*pageSize;

    //Query the DB and if no errors, send all the patients
    let total = await Patient.count({});
    console.log(total); // will log the real count
    let query = Patient.find({});
    query.skip(start);
    query.limit(pageSize);
    query.exec((err, patients) => {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        //If no errors, send them back to the client
        res.json({total:total, page:page, pageSize:pageSize, items:patients});
    });
}
```

### You can also of course use callback on `count` function :

```
Patient.count({}, (error, count) => {
  if(error) res.send(error);
  // work with total
});
```

Comment: Great explanation. I have understood the benefits of using async/await. Thank you.